# Why useFocusEffect doesn't notice when the screen is not on focus and comes back to focus

Tags: javascript, react-native

What I want is to notice when the user is on the app screen, or off the application(in the setting screen in this case)
The reason Im doing this is because I want to check the permissions of the user if it's "denied" or "granted".
and if its "denied" to not allow the user to navigate to other screen, and if its "granted" to allow the user to navigate to other screen.

```
const PermissionsIntro = ({ navigation}) => {
     async function configurePushNotifications() {
    const { status } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = status;
    console.log('status of notification', status)
    if(status === 'granted'){
      setNavigate(true)
    }
    else if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
      setNavigate(false)
    }
    else if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      setNavigate(false)
      Alert.alert('Permission required', 'Push notifications need the appropriate permissions.');
      return;
    }

    const pushTokenData = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
    setExpoPushToken(pushTokenData.data);

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
        name: 'default',
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.DEFAULT,
      });
    }
  }

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      configurePushNotifications();
      alert('screen is on application')

      console.log('tfffffff')

      return () => {
        openSettings()
        console.log('screen is on settings')
        // alert('screen is on settings')
      };
    }, [])
  );

  const openSettings = () => {
    Linking.openSettings();
  };
  
 //onPress function
  const confirm = () => {
    console.log('navigate', navigate);

    if (navigate == true) {
      navigation.navigate('CreateProfile');
    } 
    else {
      console.log('turn the permissions to true!');
      openSettings();
    }
  };
}
```

When I navigate to this screen it showed me the alert `alert(screen is on application)`,
but when I go to the settings and go back to the application the useFocusEffect is not called at all.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

useFocusEffect is not able to run when app is coming to foreground/background unfortunately. In this case you should use AppState instead. AppState can tell you if the app is in the foreground or background, and notify you when the state changes. More can be found in the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate).